# ggplot2 contour binwidth/bins default

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

What is the default value for the parameter **bins/binwidth** of **geom_contour**?

I couldn't find it in the help of the function.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-contour.r) for `stat_contour`. The number of bins and their breaks are set in `StatContour`'s `compute_group` function definition:

```
compute_group = function(data, scales, bins = NULL, binwidth = NULL,
                           breaks = NULL, complete = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE) {
    # If no parameters set, use pretty bins
    if (is.null(bins) && is.null(binwidth) && is.null(breaks)) {
      breaks <- pretty(range(data$z), 10)
    }
    # If provided, use bins to calculate binwidth
    if (!is.null(bins)) {
      binwidth <- diff(range(data$z)) / bins
    }
    # If necessary, compute breaks from binwidth
    if (is.null(breaks)) {
      breaks <- fullseq(range(data$z), binwidth)
    }

    contour_lines(data, breaks, complete = complete)
}
```

You can provide `geom_contour`/`stat_contour` with your own number of bins or a binwidth, or with a vector of breaks. If these are all null, `breaks` is set to approximately 10 pretty breaks covering the range of your `z` variable. Pretty break calculations take the number of breaks, `n` that you would *like*, but based on the actual data and how "pretty" (e.g. whole numbers, even numbers, multiples of 5, multiples of 10) your breaks are, you may end up with more or less than 10 breaks.

So, there is no static default binwidth or number of bins, because it depends on your data. The closest you could say is the default is roughly 10 bins.

Answer (score 0):

The default `binwidth` is **30** unless it is overwritten. You cannot find it because due to the lack of the usage, many functions don't support it anymore. `geom_bar()` used to support it before but now if you use it you'll get a warning telling to you use `geom_histogram()` instead. The default `bins` for histogram is also **30**. Although, I'm not sure that you can use `binwidth` in `geom_contour()`

Comment: This answer is correct for some geoms, like `geom_histogram`, but is incorrect for `geom_contour`. Look at the source code. And yes, `geom_contour` can take arguments for either `bins` or `binwidth`; both are done in examples in the docs.

Comment: omg, my life is a lie. I've always thought that there must be a default argument for bins because some function documentation provides NULL as the argument. Thanks for pointing out that data varying bins are possible.

Comment: Sorry to break it to you! (Get it? `breaks`?)